# Numerically integrate a plotted function

Tags: numerical-integration

I used `Plot[NIntegrate[...]...]` to plot a function of 5 different variables. It took really long. Right now I need to integrate this function one more time over the 5th variable and plot the result. Can someone tell me if there is an option to `Nintegrate` the plot to speed things up? Maybe there's a way to convert the plot to a list of $x$ and $y$ and then take a sum over $(y2-y1)\,(x2-x1)$ and list plot it or something similar?

I guess it's not gonna work for me. I have the following function:

```
f[ρ_, ϕ_, ζ_, ξ_, r_] := 2.*100.*20.*0.02*0.2*ρ*Cos[ϕ]*Sech[20*(ρ - 1.)]^2.*ζ*Exp[-ζ]*
    BesselJ[0, 100.*ζ*Sqrt[r^2. + ρ^2. - 2.*r*ρ*Cos[ϕ]]]*(Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]*
    Cosh[10.*Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]*(ξ + 1.)] + ζ*Sinh[10.*Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]
    *(ξ + 1.)])/((2.*ζ^2. + 0.02^2.)*Sinh[10.*Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]] + 
    2.*ζ*Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]*Cosh[10.*Sqrt[ζ^2. + 0.02^2.]])
```

Here the function $f$ have 5 variables: $\rho,\ \phi,\ \zeta,\ \xi,\ r.$. First, I need to integrate over $\rho,\ \phi,\ \zeta,\ \xi.$ and plot $f=f(r).$ It takes about 1 hour. I use as I said before

```
Plot[NIntegrate[f, {ξ, -1., 0.}, {ζ, 0., ∞}, {ϕ, -3.1415, +3.1415}, {ρ, 0., ∞}], {r, 0, 10}]
```

The next step is I need to integrate one more time over $r$, `{r,0,r1}`and plot it over `{r1,0,7}`. I tried what you've said, but I failed. Is your method with NDsolve going to work with this kind of function?

Comment: See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364088/mathematica-how-to-obtain-data-points-plotted-by-plot-command).

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your question.  Can you clarify why you want to tie together the plotting w.r.t `r` and the integration w.r.t `r`?  Is your motivation performance?  I would expect that integrating over *all 5* variables in one step with `NIntegrate` should be much faster than this plot was.  You can also speed up plotting by limiting the number of plot points.  Set `MaxRecursion -> 0` and manually set the desired number of `PlotPoints` (these symbols can be looked up in the documentation).

Comment: But it would be even better to not use `Plot` but build a `Table` of the values, which you can store for later, and the `ListPlot` them.  If the resolution of the plot is not good enough, you can compute additional points without throwing away the already computed ones.  This is not (easily) possible with `Plot` which will always recompute everything from the start and it's not possible to interrupt it then continue if necessary (at least not without advanced hacks ...)

Answer (score 16):

The trick is to use `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate` and thus in effect obtain a numerical antiderivative that can be evaluated *fast* at different points.  `NIntegrate` will only do definite integration, so it needs to be run each time the integration bounds are changed.  This is very slow, as you noticed.  `NDSolve` will only need to be run once.

#### Slow way (what you used)

We are going to integrate `f`:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x^2]

F[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}]

Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

It took 5 seconds on my machine.

```
NIntegrate[F[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.686052, 2.63519} *)
```

Both integration and plotting are slow with this method.  For complex functions, they can be prohibitively slow.

#### Fast way (`NDSolve`)

```
iF = NDSolveValue[{F2'[x] == f[x], F2[0] == 0}, F2, {x, 0, 5}]
```

`iF` is an interpolating function.

```
Plot[iF[x], {x, 0, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This took about 0.02 seconds.

Here's a not so widely known trick: the antiderivative of an interpolating function can be computed *exactly* using `Integrate` (not `NIntegrate`).  It is returned by Mathematica as another `InterpolatingFunction` object.  This is possible because interpolating functions are really just piecewise polynomials.  Derivatives can be taken too.

So we can compute the second integral directly (and very quickly) as

```
Integrate[iF[x], {x, 0, 5}]

(* 2.63519 *)
```

Another trick: To get the antiderivative as a function object directly, you can also do

```
Derivative[-1][iF]
```

The disadvantage of the fast way is that there's less oversight about precision loss and numerical errors.  To make sure that the final integration result is accurate enough (despite error accumulation), you must make sure that `NDSolve` computes `iF` with sufficient accuracy.

Comment: "Here's a not so widely known trick": in some sense, this trick should be obvious, but it clearly isn't. +1 for showing the tricks!

Comment: I added some details. Could you check it out?

Comment: @LexRomah Right, this method won't work for you.  :-(

Comment: sorry, but doesn't your method work for a function of several variables?