# How can we plot gamma function numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration

[image]

How can we plot this integration for m=1,\theta = 0.2? Here r_h(lower limit) = 1.

Comment: Please enter your expressions in correctly formatted, copy-and-pasteable *Mathematica* code.

Comment: `NIntegrate[]` could be used, but a faster way would be to formulate the equivalent ODE and use `NDSolve[]`.

Comment: Per @J.M.'s comment, see for instance [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104553/29734).

Comment: t = \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(r\)]\(1/\((1 - 
      4\ m\ /\((r \[Sqrt]\[Pi])\) {GammaRegularized[3/2, 
         r^2/\((4  \[Theta])\)]})\) \[DifferentialD]r\)\)

Comment: Put the code in your question, please; however, Copy As > Input Text would be much better for you and for us.

Answer (score 1):

Just picking up the idea mentioned in the comments, your code would be

```
f[r_] := 1/(1 - 4/(r*Sqrt[Pi])*Gamma[1.5, r^2/(4*0.2)])
F[y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[r], {r, 1, y}]

LogLogPlot[F[r], {r, 1, 100}]
```