# Plotting indefinite integral that has no closed form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

How do I plot $\int \sin (\cos (x)) \, dx$ or any other indefinite integral that   cannot be evaluated in terms of standard mathematical functions?

On the other hand Mathematica is able to plot this $\int_1^2 \sin (y \cos (x)) \, dx$ as a function of y:

```
Plot[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(2\)]\(Sin[
    y*Cos[x]] \[DifferentialD]x\)\), {y, 0, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Plot` needs expressions that can be evaluated to numerical values when replacing the plot variable by a numerical value. In order to plot a stem function (note that it is not uniquely defined), you can use `NIntegrate` as follows:

```
F = t \[Function] NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[x]], {x, 0, t}];
Plot[F[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: if performance matters see here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104553/2079

Comment: @george2079 Goode one! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

To embellish upon Henrik's answer

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[Cos[x]], {x, 0, t}]

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

To find the min and max

```
#[{f[t], 0 < t < 7}, t] & /@ {NMinimize, NMaximize}

(* {{-0.893244, {t -> 4.71239}}, {0.893244, {t -> 1.5708}}} *)
```

Or

```
{t, f[t]} /. (FindRoot[f'[t], {t, #}] & /@ 
    Range[1.5, 17, 3]) // Column
```

[image]