# plotted function and Numerically integrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I want to speed up drawing of a function. The answer is here [Numerically integrate a plotted function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/numerically-integrate-a-plotted-function/104553#104553). But only one problem: it doesn't work for function of several variables. I tried to generalize it, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is my example.

I start with solving an equation:

```
eqn = j - Sqrt[q^2 + qp^2 - 2*q*qp*Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
         Sqrt[qp^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
                  Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
                      4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*qp^2)])] == 0; 
With[{gensol = Solve[eqn, qp]}, 
     Block[{m = 5.5, M = 300, Nc = 3, 
         c = ScientificForm[-44687.3983417778], 
         b = ScientificForm[161593.81818181818], 
         k1 = ScientificForm[16.485010961790245], 
         k2 = ScientificForm[-13.131344420001051], ma, mp, j}, 
       {j = Sqrt[q^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 + 
                     Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
                         4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*q^2)])], 
          ma = Sqrt[-2*(M^2 - 2*(3*k1 + k2)*
                     (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
                          m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))^2 - c + 
                   2*m5^2)], mp = Sqrt[(2*b*m)/
                (Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
                   m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))]}; 
        sols = gensol]]; 
qpC12 = Compile[{{q, _Complex}, {m5, _Complex}, 
         {\[Theta], _Complex}}, Evaluate[qp /. sols[[2]]], 
       RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]; 
qp32 = Re[qpC12[q, m5, \[Theta]]];
```

Then I do:

```
f1[q_, m5_, \[Theta]_] := (q^2 qp32^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 )/
                          ((2 (2 \[Pi])^2)  Sqrt[-(2 q Cos[\[Theta]] qp32) + qp32^2 + q^2]) 

f3[q, m5, \[Theta]] = NDSolveValue[{D[f2[q, m5, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] == f1[q, m5, \[Theta]], 
f2[0, 0, 0] == 0}, f2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}]
```

An errors apear:

```
NDSolveValue::noout: No functions were specified for output from NDSolveValue.

ConstantArray::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at 
position 2 of ConstantArray[{TemporaryVariable$143960,TemporaryVariable$143961},-\[Infinity]].
```

Is there any way to do what I want? Thank you!

Comment: For a start, contemplate:
`NumericQ[1]`

`(* True *)`

`NumericQ[ScientificForm[1]]`

`(* False *)`

Comment: NDSolveValue wants numeric input.  If your only solve variable isTheta, you need to specify numeric values for q and m5.

Comment: @BillWatts numeric values for q∈[0,150] and m5∈[0,150]. How may I give NDSolveValue numeric input in such case?

Comment: * I want to plot `Plot3D[f3[q, m5, \[Theta]], {q, 0.8, 150}, {m5, 0, 150}]`

Answer (score 2):

I've corrected some things that will get you farther, but I still can't get you all the way.

First part looks ok.

```
eqn = j - Sqrt[q^2 + qp^2 - 2*q*qp*Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
    Sqrt[qp^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 - 
         Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
           4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*qp^2)])] == 0;
```

The next part, get rid of the ScientificForms.  They are for output only, and with them, your constants don't get assigned.

```
With[{gensol = Solve[eqn, qp]}, 
  Block[{m = 5.5, M = 300, Nc = 3, c = -44687.3983417778, 
    b = 161593.81818181818, k1 = 16.485010961790245, 
    k2 = -13.131344420001051, ma, mp, 
    j}, {j = 
     Sqrt[q^2 + (1/2)*(16*m5^2 + ma^2 + mp^2 + 
          Sqrt[(-(16*m5^2) - ma^2 - mp^2)^2 - 
            4*(ma^2*mp^2 - 16*m5^2*q^2)])], 
    ma = Sqrt[-2*(M^2 - 
         2*(3*k1 + 
            k2)*(Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
             m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))^2 - c + 2*m5^2)], 
    mp = Sqrt[(2*b*m)/(Sqrt[(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2)/(2*(k1 + k2))] + 
         m*(b/(2*(c + M^2 + 2*m5^2))))]};
   sols = gensol]];
```

Then

```
qpC12 = Compile[{{q, _Complex}, {m5, _Complex}, {\[Theta], _Complex}},
   Evaluate[qp /. sols[[2]]], 
  RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]
```

Its a good idea to test things at this point.

```
qpC12[75, 75, .5]
*65.7399 + 36.0074 I*
```

And add arguments to:

```
qp32[q_, m5_, \[Theta]_] = Re[qpC12[q, m5, \[Theta]]];
```

An interesting thing is your problem has almost not dependence on the variable `m5`,as shown by the plot.

```
Plot[Evaluate[qp32[40, m5, .1]], {m5, 0, 150}]
```

[image]

Using other values for q and theta exhibits similar behavior.
Modify definition of f1 to include arguments of qp32.

```
f1[q_, m5_, \[Theta]_] := (q^2 qp32[q, 
      m5, \[Theta]]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/((2 (2 \[Pi])^2) Sqrt[-(2 q Cos[\[Theta]] qp32[q, m5, \[Theta]]) + qp32[q, m5, \[Theta]]^2 + q^2])
```

f1 now works

```
Plot[Evaluate[f1[q, 30, .1]], {q, 0, 150}]
```

[image]

The next part I have only been able to work by assigning q and m5 prior to the NDSolveValue

```
q = 19;
m5 = 20;
f2sol = NDSolveValue[{D[f2[\[Theta]], \[Theta]] == f1[q, m5, \[Theta]], f2[0] == 0}, f2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}]

Plot[f2sol[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}]
```

[image]

And some values of q and m5 don't work at all.  You know what you want better than I do and maybe this can help you to debug further.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how it can generalize to Plot3D? If i do f2sol[q, m5] =  NDSolveValue[{D[f2[q, m5, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] == 
    f1[q, m5, \[Theta]], D[f2[q, m5, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] == 0}, 
  f2, {\[Theta], 0, Pi/2}]

Comment: then Plot3D[f2sol[q, m5, \[Theta]], {q, 0.8, 150}, {m5, 0, 150}] doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like the instability is coming from f1. Execute `Plot[f1[140, 20, \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
 Exclusions -> None]` to see what I mean.  You can also try `Plot3D[Evaluate[f1[q, 20, \[Theta]]], {q, 0, 150}, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]/2}]`.  The high discontinuity in f1 is creating problems with the whole solution.